# HTML5 Audio Visualization?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, visualization

I saw a page on [Visualizations with Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API) that explained how to make a visualization. I tried that exact code and got errors like "ReferenceError: stream is not defined" and others. Is there a way to make a visualization that works from an audio element? It only matters if it works on FireFox.

Comment: Which block of code did you try ? There are tons of them on this page.

Comment: I copied all the code up to "Creating a waveform/oscilloscope" and then I copied all the code from "Creating a frequency bar graph" to the end because I need the bar graph visualization.

Comment: @JohnWhite - those are just snippets intended to be integrated into your own code. As such, they are not fully functioning examples. Actually, if you look closely at the note at the top of the page, before the heading **Basic Concepts**, it says: `Note: You can find working examples of all the code snippets in our Voice-change-O-matic demo.` It even includes a link, check it out.

Comment: @enhzflep I went on that site, but it makes the visualization from the microphone. Is there a way to base the visualization from an audio element?

Comment: @JohnWhite - Sorry, I missed that part of your initial post. I'd probably just look for another example somewhere if I were you.Though, you may find that you need to make changes to the code around here: `source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);` I reckon that instead of creating a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` object, you could probably create a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` from your data. For more, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is:

```
    let audio = document.getElementById("yourAudioElement");

    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    let ctx = new window.AudioContext();

    // add the audio element node as source for AudioContext instance
    let sourceNode = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    // if you wish to visualize the audio then you will have to connect this to an analyzer
    let analyzer = ctx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.6;
    analyser.fftSize = 512; // frequency sample size 

    // set frequency data
    let frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    // connect source node to analyser to collect frequency data
    sourceNode.connect(this.analyser);

    // connect this source to the audio output (your speaker device)
    sourceNode.connect(ctx.destination);

    // you can then start your audio as below
    audio.play();

    // then you can animate the frequence data by calling requestAnimationFrame()
    // this method allows you to keep updating your visualization by frames
    function renderFrame() {
        // you need to check whether audio is playing here to control this recursive call
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

        // then just use your imagination to animate the frequency data by frame
        // you can update your canvas here
    }
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

// Create the instance of AudioContext
var context = new AudioContext();

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia       ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

// Access microphone
var medias = {audio : true, video : false};

/**
 * @param {MediaStream|LocalMediaStream} stream
 */
var successCallback = function(stream) {
    // Create the instance of MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
    var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // code for visualization
    // do something ...
};

/**
 * @param {NavigatorUserMediaError|MediaStreamError} error
 */
var errorCallback = function(error) {
    console.error(error);
};

navigator.getUserMedia(medias, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

[XSound.js](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/XSound) is very useful library for Web Audio API.